# how to save data using shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, get, sharedpreferences

i am new developer in android application.i have used shared preference concept to share the data from one activity to another activity.i have implemented code as follows

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TableLayout table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
         table.removeAllViews();
        String sName = null;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            TableRow row=new TableRow(Main.this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            TextView  name=new TextView(Main.this);

            name.setText(" HAI PRASAD"+i);

          sName=name.getText().toString();

            Log.v("sName 1111111","-->"+sName);

             getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).edit().putString("NAMES",sName).commit();


            name.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            name.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

              row.addView(name);

              table.addView(row);  
        }

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent it=new Intent(Main.this,Main2.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });


}
```

here i am printing a name ten times and saving with shared preference as

```
TextView  name=new TextView(Main.this);

            name.setText(" HAI PRASAD"+i);

          sName=name.getText().toString();

            Log.v("sName 1111111","-->"+sName);

             getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).edit().putString("NAMES",sName).commit();
```

here i would like to get the same data in Main2.class.the **main2.java** as follows

```
public class Main2 extends Activity 
{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    String name=getSharedPreferences("Values", 0).getString("NAMES", "");

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(name);
}
```

but here i am getting only one name that as HAI PRASAD9

how can i get one by one

> HAI PRASAD0 HAI PRASAD1 HAI PRASAD2
>   HAI PRASAD3 HAI PRASAD4 ......so on?

please any one can help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have multiple keys for storing multiple items. Something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        getSharedPreferences("Values" + i, 0).edit().putString("Key" + i, "STring" + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        getSharedPreferences("Values" + i, 0).getString("Key" + i, "");
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if i use in your way that last name only display ten times i mean HAI PRASAD9

Comment: You didn't understand my answer. You're modifying an item under a key ten times. But I advice you to use 10 keys, you can create them dynamically in a loop and store your values under those keys.

Comment: i mean i am getting out put as HAI PRASAD00 HAI PRASAD11 HAI PRASAD22 and so on here my question is i want get like HAI PRASAD0 HAI PRASAD1 HAI PRASAD2 and so on

Comment: So what's the problem? I don't believe you can't figure it out by yourself, do you really need my help?