# I want to save my Data using Shared Preferences if possible

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my code below, I use a listView and a Custom Array adapter to create a list that stores meetings.(people involved, Description, date and time). I have been looking on stack overflow and came upon shared preferences. I don't really know how to use it though. Any help is much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults;
private FloatingActionButton add;
private FloatingActionButton clear;
ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
final Context context = this;
String time1, people1, description1, mDate, hour, minute, MeridiemIndicator, dateNumber;
int Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    searchResults = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    final CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.custom_row_view, results);
    lv1.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    add = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {

            dialogMethod(lv1);
        }


    });

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            adapter.remove(results.get(position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
    lv1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
            CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            adapter.remove(results.get(position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialogMethod(lv1);

            return true;
        }


    });
    clear = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            results.clear();
            CustomAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.custom_row_view, results);
            lv1.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    });
}




public void dialogMethod(final ListView lv1) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_meeting);
    dialog.setTitle("Meeting");

    //ingredient.getText().toString();

    final EditText people = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.people);
    if (people.getText().toString().length() == 0)
        people.setError("Required");
    final EditText description = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.description);
    if (description.getText().toString().length() == 0)
        description.setError("Required");
    FloatingActionButton save = (FloatingActionButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.save);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom ingredient_dialog
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePicker cal = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
            Year = cal.getYear();
            Month = cal.getMonth();
            Day = cal.getDayOfMonth();
            Month = Month + 1;

            TimePicker time = (TimePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.clock);
            Hour = time.getHour();
            Minute = time.getMinute();

            dialog.dismiss();
            time1 = hour + ":" + minute + MeridiemIndicator;
            people1 = people.getText().toString();
            description1 = description.getText().toString();

            mDate = Year + "/" + Month + "/" + Day;
            dateNumber = Year + "";
            if (Month < 10) {
                dateNumber += "0" + Month;
            } else {
                dateNumber += Month;
            }
            if (Day < 10) {
                dateNumber += "0" + Day;
            } else {
                dateNumber += Day;
            }


            ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();
            lv1.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_row_view, searchResults));


        }
    });
    dialog.show();


}
private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults() {


    SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
    sr1.setName("  Meeting With: " + people1);
    sr1.setTimeOfMeeting("  Starts At: " + time1);
    sr1.setDescription("  Details: " + description1);
    sr1.setDate("  Date: " + mDate);
    sr1.setDateNumber(dateNumber);
    results.add(sr1);
    Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<SearchResults>() {
        public int compare(SearchResults x, SearchResults y) {
            return Integer.parseInt(x.getDateNumber()) - Integer.parseInt(y.getDateNumber());
        }
    });


    return results;
  }
}
```

Also here is my Custom Adapter code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, int custom_row_view, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
    super(context,custom_row_view,results);

    searchArrayList = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

public int getCount() {
    return searchArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txtTimeOfMeeting = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeOfMeeting);
        holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txtTimeOfMeeting.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTimeOfMeeting());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.txtDate.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDate());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtTimeOfMeeting;
    TextView txtDescription;
    TextView txtDate;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [how-to-save-data-using-shared-preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015197/how-to-save-data-using-shared-preferences)

Comment: You better should use a Database as you will need to save a list, Shared Preferences will be use for one entry or two...

Answer (score 0):

You can make JsonObject (or JsonArray) and save it as String (**jsonObject.toString()** or **jsonArray.toString()** )

JsonObject && array tutorial -> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

And then just get or save your String

```
public String getMeetings(){
        // ctx is Contex e.g> getApplicationContext()
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx); 
        return sharedPreferences.getString("key_name", "[]"); // return from shared preferences, if there is nothing for key_name the return will be empty array
    }

    public void setMeetings(String your_list_asJsonString){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("key_name", your_list_asJsonString); // Here you save your string in shared preferences, and than you can access it with key_name
        editor.commit(); // or editor.apply()
    }
```

There are lot of ways

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of storing data on your app in Android:

- SharedPreferences
- Device Storage/SD Card Storage
- SQLite

Based on the kind of data, the storage medium for the data should be chosen.

- An image file should be stored as a JPEG/PNG file on the Device Storage and be accessible from outside the app if need be. It doesn't make sense to store an Image encoded as a byte stream in SharedePreferences/SQLite.
- Some data in a fixed format(like yours), which has to be shown in a list etc. should be stored in SQL as it provides a very ordered way of storing data.
- Miscellaneous data such as User Account info, which is not repeatable in nature and is of unstructured form should be stored in the device's SharedPreferences(At least I store such data as Account Info etc. in SharedPreferences).

So much for the theoretical part. Since you have a list, the format of data to be displayed in each list item is relatively structured and will need to be accessed frequently, and in this case, I would suggest it is better to use a database to save your data, as CRUD operations in SQLite is pretty easy to achieve. To learn about SQLite go through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) for SQLite on the [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) site.